# "Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification" is raised when my app is removed from recent apps

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-remoteview

I'm trying to make an demo which can show a custom notification periodically.

To do that, I used Remoteviews to update the view of a notification. Put this notification into onReceive method of an BroadcastReceiver. Then call it periodically by using AlarmManager.

Everything works just fine **unless my demo application is removed from recent applications**. It's force crashed and when I checked in the android log, I saw this error : **"Bad notification posted - Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification"**

Could you please help me solve this ?

Below is my code :

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, PeriodicTaskReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
int interval = 10000;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

PeriodicTaskReceiver is my customized BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        repository = new LocalRepository();
        Notification(context, repository.getData());
        }
    }
```

Notification method :

```
public void Notification(Context context, Data data) {
        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = context.getString(R.string.notificationtitle);
        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);
        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        RemoteViews customNotification = buildNotificationItem(data);

        // Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setContent(customNotification);

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
//        notification.bigContentView = customNotification;
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

And the method handle the content for my Remoteviews :

```
private RemoteViews buildNotificationItem(Data data){
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(Global.PACKAGE_NAME, R.layout.notification_item);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_tags, data.getTitle());
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_content, data.getContent());
        return view;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What does your `notification_item` layout look like?